# SQL Server 2012 FK doesn't work in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012

Had a super weird issue using Entity Framework (4.x, 5) with SQL Server 2012.

To illustrate I made two tables with very simple 1-to-many relationship

```
PK. [User].[UserId] 
FK. [Order].[UserId]
```

However EF didn't generate any navigation property for these two tables at all. In the EDMX the two tables are totally separate; no link between them at all.

Then I create the same tables using the same scripts in SQL Server 2008, and all of a sudden everything works as intended as they always have been.

Has anyone had same issues? Is there any solutions for that?

I'm using the SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition from MSDN

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Users] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Users]
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to be more specific about your actual schema and constraint creation scripts, but I can tell you that EF will not map relationships that are created over unique indexes (rather than primary keys). While SQL Server allows for this, EF does not.

Comment: I've updated with SQL scripts for two tables, they are super basic ones, with UserID as the FK. Which I do all the time in SQL 2008, no problems.